# How mark all value=1 in type radio in browser (Google Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, radio-button, command, checked

I have special question maybe. I need mark all value="1" in browser (Google Chrome) without any plugins. Some way throught the address bar or developer tools, console.. so the some a command for the browser. I need it for school, mark extensive "radio" form.

Demonstration of how it looks shorter form in html code, that I need to mark all values with value=1.

```
<input name="test_warehouse" value="ans_1" type="hidden">Question 1<br>
<label><input id="ans_12" name="ans_1_w_r" value="2" type="radio">Answer 11 </label>
<br>
<label><input id="ans_13" name="ans_1_w_r" value="3" type="radio">Answer 12 </label>
<br>
<label><input id="ans_14" name="ans_1_w_r" value="4" type="radio">Answer 13 </label>
<br>
<label><input id="ans_11" name="ans_1_w_r" value="1" type="radio">Answer 13 </label>    
<input name="test_warehouse" value="ans_2" type="hidden">Question 2<br>
<label><input id="ans_23" name="ans_2_w_r" value="3" type="radio">Answer 21 </label>
<br>
<label><input id="ans_21" name="ans_2_w_r" value="1" type="radio">Answer 22 </label>
<br>
<label><input id="ans_22" name="ans_2_w_r" value="2" type="radio">Answer 23 </label>
<br>
<label><input id="ans_24" name="ans_2_w_r" value="4" type="radio">Answer 24 </label> 
<input name="test_warehouse" value="tst_3" type="hidden">Question 3<br>
<label><input id="ans_32" name="ans_3_w_r" value="2" type="radio">Answer 31 </label>
<br>
<label><input id="ans_33" name="ans_3_w_r" value="3" type="radio">Answer 32 </label>
<br>
<label><input id="ans_31" name="ans_3_w_r" value="1" type="radio">Answer 33 </label>
<br>
<label><input id="ans_34" name="ans_3_w_r" value="4" type="radio">Answer 34 </label>
```

or look on demo form  here: http://dotin.cz/test/test_mark.html  and try it mark all values with value=1

Thanks and sorry for my English maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[value="1"]'), function(element) { element.checked = 'checked' });
```

Comment: ok and where do I insert it?
I can't insert html, javascript or php.. I can only work with a browser. 
Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Either developer tools console, or (if you prefix with `javascript:`) the address bar. Exactly as you wrote in your question.

Comment: yes, prefix working well! Thank you very much! This is amazing. Much are you helped me.